# How to get the real sql query of a view?

Tags: views

One of drupal view displays reviews based on a selected event. It should display 3 reviews but instead it displays only 2. It doesn't happen for all the events and only for certain events instead of 3 it displays 2 items. As the data is all correct and I have validated the same. I wanted to see the query that is being used. The query that is displayed in the view is not helping me either. If I copy paste the same and run the sql, it throws a lot of error. 
How can I debug and see what is the query that got executed for that particular view? 
The view has relationsships and also it uses contextual filters.
Thanks

Comment: What errors you are referring to when you execute the query given by the Views UI? If you post a sample of a query, someone could probably explain.

Answer (score 5):

The query displayed in the administration UI contains database prefixing brackets. You can remove those brackets to have valid SQL that can be executed by any SQL client.

Comment: Yes I tried removing those {} brackets but still its not working.There are few lines like 'field_collection_item' AS field_data_field_art_id_field_collection_item_entity_type, 
'node' AS field_data_field_magazine_published_date_node_entity_type, 'node' AS field_data_field_book_review_synopsis_node_entity_type. How does sql interprets it?

Comment: Aliasing ("column AS alias") is valid SQL syntax. Without knowing the SQL client error, it's hard to know what it doesn't like about the query.

Answer (score 3):

The Devel module has a setting that will show all executed queries in the footer.

Comment: Yeah, but it keeps the data placeholders. I want to actually see the real query.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [hook_views_pre_execute](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_pre_execute/7) and with Devel installed use [`dpq`](https://api.drupal.org/api/devel/devel.module/function/dpq/7) to view the SQL String:

```
function hook_views_pre_execute(&$view) {
  dpq($view->build_info['query']);
}
```